# How to use substrate archive for custom chains?

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-archive, astar

In the [substrate archive wiki](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-archive/wiki), they showed how to archive the polkadot chain's data. Now I want to get other chains' data (like a substrate template node or Astar, Moonbeam, etc). How can I do that?

In the `node-template-archive/archive.toml` file, I changed the network rockdb directory appropriately.
This is the command I used for Shiden network (Astar testnet)

```
./node-template-archive -c /home/minhnd/Documents/substrate/substrate-archive/bin/node-template-archive/archive.toml
```

The log:

```
[14:51] DEBUG Archive Config: ArchiveConfig { chain: ChainConfig { data_path: Some("/home/minhnd/Documents/substrate/Astar/freshdi_shibuya/chains/shiden/db/full"), cache_size: 128, rocksdb_secondary_path: Some("./substrate_archive/rocksdb_secondary"), spec: Some(ChainSpec(name = "Development", id = "dev")) }, runtime: RuntimeConfig { exec_method: Interpreted, block_workers: 4, wasm_pages: Some(2048), wasm_runtime_overrides: None, code_substitutes: {}, storage_mode: BlockBody }, database: Some(DatabaseConfig { url: "postgres://localhost?dbname=polkadot-archive&user=postgres&password=123" }), control: ControlConfig { task_timeout: 20, max_block_load: 100000, task_url: "amqp://localhost:5672", storage_indexing: true }, log: LoggerConfig { std: Debug, file: None }, wasm_tracing: Some(TracingConfig { targets: "wasm_tracing,pallet,frame,state", folder: None }) }
[14:51] INFO Open RocksDB at /home/minhnd/Documents/substrate/Astar/freshdi_shibuya/chains/shiden/db/full, state column budget: 115 MiB, others(11) column cache: 1 MiB
[14:51] DEBUG DB Opened blockchain db, fetched best = 0xe1b8d4c234012350df9aa4ff6b26585d8b7ad431929d4bb958d280f403069492 (313726)
[14:51] DEBUG DB Opened blockchain db, fetched final = 0xf1cf9022c7ebb34b162d5b5e34e705a5a740b2d0ecc1009fb89023e62a488108 (0)
[14:51] DEBUG DB Opened blockchain db, fetched final_state = 0xf1cf9022c7ebb34b162d5b5e34e705a5a740b2d0ecc1009fb89023e62a488108 (0)
[14:51] DEBUG block_gap=None
[14:51] DEBUG DB Opened blockchain db, fetched best = 0xe1b8d4c234012350df9aa4ff6b26585d8b7ad431929d4bb958d280f403069492 (313726)
[14:51] DEBUG DB Opened blockchain db, fetched final = 0xf1cf9022c7ebb34b162d5b5e34e705a5a740b2d0ecc1009fb89023e62a488108 (0)
[14:51] DEBUG DB Opened blockchain db, fetched final_state = 0xf1cf9022c7ebb34b162d5b5e34e705a5a740b2d0ecc1009fb89023e62a488108 (0)
[14:51] DEBUG block_gap=None
[14:51] DEBUG allocator being destroyed, max_total_size 416, max_bumper 1104128
[14:51] DEBUG Prepared new runtime version Some(RuntimeVersion { spec_name: RuntimeString::Owned("shiden"), impl_name: RuntimeString::Owned("shiden"), authoring_version: 1, spec_version: 1, impl_version: 0, apis: [([223, 106, 203, 104, 153, 7, 96, 155], 3), ([55, 227, 151, 252, 124, 145, 245, 228], 1), ([64, 254, 58, 212, 1, 248, 149, 154], 5), ([210, 188, 152, 151, 238, 208, 143, 21], 2), ([247, 139, 39, 139, 229, 63, 69, 76], 2), ([188, 157, 137, 144, 79, 91, 146, 63], 1), ([55, 200, 187, 19, 80, 169, 162, 168], 1), ([171, 60, 5, 114, 41, 31, 235, 139], 1), ([234, 147, 227, 241, 111, 61, 105, 98], 1)], transaction_version: 1, state_version: 0 }) in 86 ms.
[14:51] DEBUG Allocated WASM instance 1/4
[14:51] INFO Running archive for  `shiden`, implementation `shiden`. Latest known runtime version: 1. Latest finalized block 0xf1cf…8108 ️
[14:51] DEBUG No cached session for DNSNameRef("localhost")
[14:51] DEBUG Not resuming any session
[14:51] DEBUG No cached session for DNSNameRef("localhost")
[14:51] DEBUG Not resuming any session
[14:51] DEBUG Using ciphersuite TLS13_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
[14:51] DEBUG Not resuming
[14:51] DEBUG TLS1.3 encrypted extensions: []
[14:51] DEBUG ALPN protocol is None
[14:51] DEBUG Ticket saved
[14:51] DEBUG Ticket saved
[14:51] INFO relation "_sqlx_migrations" already exists, skipping
Error: Expected chain polkadot got shiden
```

So I got this `Expected chain polkadot got shiden` error message. I really don't know what to do and how to solve this.

Comment: What have you tried? What problem are you running into? Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @dvdplm's answer is right, node-template archive is the place to get started with this. If you want to index a custom chain like Shiden you will also want to edit the imported runtime to reflect shiden's `RuntimeApi` and `Block` type to point to the ones from shiden https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-archive/blob/eeb593ed13867642c9b80a39556a75a36c4e47bc/bin/node-template-archive/src/main.rs#L23

Comment: The error is a safety check to make sure that whatever runtime archive is running is the one it expects. It checks the runtime of the locally-run chain and the runtime that polkadot-archive is using and found a mismatch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem. Before I had run the Shiden network, I run the command for polkadot network and I forgot to delete the postgres db (or change the path in the config file to the new db). After creating a new postgres db and change the uri in the config file, the problem solved.

Answer (score 5):

The substrate template node is available [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-archive/tree/master/bin/node-template-archive) and you can run it with `cargo run --release --bin node-template-archive`. As for indexing parachains I am actually not sure but I believe it could be as easy as simply providing the chain spec and point it to the rocksdb folder.
If that doesn't work feel free to open a feature request!